# ViewEncapsulation.Emulated styles are copied into #shadow-root by a ViewEncapsulation.(Native|ShadowDom) component

Tags: angular, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a sample repository https://github.com/collinstevens/angular-encapsulation which demonstrates my question.

There are three components: EmulatedComponent, NativeComponent, and ShadowDomComponent which using ViewEncapsulation.Emulated, ViewEncapsulation.Native, and ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom respectively.

The styles from the EmulatedComponent are copied into the `<head>` as described on https://angular.io/guide/component-styles, but are also copied into each #shadow-root and I would like to know why, and how to prevent this if possible.

**`emulated.component.scss`**

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**`native.component.scss`**

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**`shadow-dom.component.scss`**

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5059), the workaround at the moment is to basically not mix encapsulation modes.

But the scenario i assume you are encountering might be that you are mixing third parties having different types of encapsulation modes? If so you either have to take in consideration of your css structure or just simply rethink what third-party lib you are mixing.

**Update**

In consideration to comment make all components to run native encapsulation by telling compiler to do so with [compilerOptions](https://angular.io/api/core/CompilerOptions) in order to not conflict with native web components.

Do so by adding in your tsconfig.json file(it's tsconfig.app.json in ng version 6+):

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "defaultEncapsulation": 1
}
```

Comment: Well I'm trying to distribute web components built with angular elements using shadow-dom so that other teams within my company can reuse them, whether or not they are in angular but noticed we are running into this issue with angular consuming angular elements. I figured there was an open issue around it, but my google-fu failed me.

Comment: @CollinStevens Do you know if you specify encapsulation on each component(easily search and replace if so)? If not then you could actually change to set the default encapsulation to native with compiler options(see post update), however that would still be a risk overall on unwanted changes.

Comment: I'm not trying to make everything ViewEncapsulation.Native because ShadowDom v0 has little support https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom. We are aiming for ShadowDom v1 since it is a WIP by multiple browsers at the moment, https://caniuse.com/#search=shadow%20dom%20v1. We are going to distribute web components built using angular elements that use ShadowDom v1. If the consuming angular application using ViewEncapsulation.Emulated, we will be running into this bug; we're trying not to enforce the consuming applications to use a specific encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

the main difference between three:

1- `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` it preprocessing css code to deep scope to the component to prevent conflict and that's the default mode for angular because of shadow dom limited support in browsers... for browser support [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1)

2- `ViewEncapsulation.Native` which is using deprecated version of shadow dom according to angular doc [Read](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).
it working almost the same like shadow dom encapsulation

3- `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` when you using `ShadowDom` the why is copied the style in every #shadow-root because that's how it work... when you active `ShadowDom` it allow to hidden DOM trees to attached to the regular tree it's like tree inside regular DOM tree therefore it copy style that applies on elements by making high level scope and what you see practically is the shadow dom but theoretically is the regular DOM...

for more further reading about Shadow Dom [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

for best practice and what angular team recommend with is using `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` which is default but in some rarely cases you use `None` or `ShadowDom` but use it with caution.

Comment: I understand that ViewEncapsulation.Native is using ShadowDom v0 and ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom is using ShadowDom v1 and I understand ViewEncapsulation.Emulated is essentially ShadyCSS. The question is why are the styles from the EmulatedComponent copied into the #shadow-roots? The documentation for ViewEncapsulation.Emulated states then scoped styles will be placed in the <head>.

Answer (score 0):

It is still the case today. Any workaround beside "Not mixing ViewEncapsulation" which is not a really good solution from the Angular Team. :/